# Instrument key vs sheet music key

Tags: theory, sheet-music, transposition

I have a logic problem in my head. Let me first state what I know.

- recorder in A key with all closed holes plays an A.
- recorder in C key with all closed holes plays a C.
- in sheet music a C sits one bar below the lowest bar.

When the sheet music has no sharps or bs at the front and it states explicitly to be for Recorder in A key, does that mean I have to use the same fingerings as if I were playing a C key recorder meaning all holes closed on the a key recorder represent a C or do I have to change the fingerings and the C from the music is two holes open at the a key recorder.

What does it mean if a piece explicitly states to be for a specific keyed instrument but then be in a different key itself? Something is not adding up here.

Is the note one bar below the lowest always a (b)C(#) ? and what has the instrument key to do with that?

Comment: omfg this is the worst! so you end up calculating the actual key by combining the sheet music key with key of the instrument it is intended for and hope for the best?

Comment: There´s no calculation. You take the instrument the music asks for and play the music as written. The composer/arranger/copyist does the transposition.

Comment: A recorder in the key of A? that's unusual.

Comment: @PiedPiper recorders, like trombones, traditionally are not transposing instruments.

Comment: @phoog Recorders are not transposing, trombones: it depends where you are (brass bands). But this is not about recorders, it's about the concept of transposing instruments and that's explained at the dupe (although I think I might need to write a clearer answer there)

Comment: It sounds like the bottom line is that something is odd about the piece of music you have. It would help get to the bottom of it if you could post an image, or link to a copy of it.

Comment: @PiedPiper trombones were not transposing instruments for several centuries before British brass bands came into being, hence "traditionally."

Comment: @phoog Brass bands are also a tradition, but we´re splitting hairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not even aware that recorders per se were *transposing* instruments. Perhaps in Austria, recorder means flute?

But, on to the question. **If** you're asking about transposing instruments, then the answer is straightforward. On a C instrument, one plays the music, from the dots, and what comes out is automatically in the correct key. On an A instrument, the music will have been *transposed* so that it is written a m3 higher, to compensate for the fact that the instrument will produce notes lower (m3) than it 'should'.

If you play an A instrument from music written for a standard (C) instrument, then what comes out will be in a different key, namely a m3 lower. That doesn't mean it will sound odd on its own - just that it won't match the key of any other instruments it's played with. Quite straightforward, really, and involves around half of all orchestral instruments.

Comment: "Not even aware that recorders per se were transposing instruments": they're not!  See my answer for a link to some fingering charts.

Comment: I was not aware of the difference transposing and not transposing instrument. I mean I was familiar with the concepts of wind instruments beeing in different keys. I thought the key the instrument is in is just the lowest note it can play. but i was completely unaware that a piece of music for lets say a Bb Trumpte that is written in C key would sound a written C on the sheet like a Bb, because you appearantly play a C on the Trumpet, but a Bb note comes out. so if you like to accompany it with a piano you have to actually play a Bb when the sheet music says C.

Comment: I thought sheet music is absolute meaning if it says A a tone around 440Hz (with or without overtones) should come out regardless of the instrument. And the instrument with its key in the headline of the sheet music just notes that it sounds best on that instrument.

Comment: @GeraldDegeneve - so I hope the explanation has enlightened you somewhat!

Comment: yes it did thats why i marked it :) thank you

Comment: A C tone around 440Hz?. That's going to be an A tone on most parts of the world!

Comment: sorry yes of course the thing you tune to is A not C ... my bad

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally recorder is not a transposing instrument.  An F recorder has the same fingering for an F major scale that a C recorder has for a C major scale, but the music is written at concert pitch.  See the fingering charts linked by the American Recorder Society for [more information](https://americanrecorder.org/recorder_fingering_charts.php).

Comment: sorry for the confusion. in german we call a tin whistle a tin flute (blechflöte) a recorder is a flute (flöte) and a flute is a crossway flute (querflöte) and i got them a little confused. but no matter question was answered :) thank you for bringing in the term concert pitch did not know that thats the thing that makes sheet music absolute A=440Hz. And if its not in concert pitch you should pay attention to the key of the instrument it is written for if you want to play it with a different instrument and get the pitch right. at least thats what i took away from the answers. thank you!

Comment: I had a feeling something was lost in the translation...